# Can I give an ID to an item in String-array?

Tags: android, xml, string

My question is simple, yet I don't know the answer.

**WHAT I WANT:**

```
<string-array name="items_array">
        <item id="id1">Item1</item>
</string-array>
```

**THIS IS WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE:**

```
<string-array name="items_array"> 
   <item>Item1</item>
</string-array>
```

What do I want to achieve with that is, that I want to offer in my `Spinner` normal names (*e.g. Martin*). Yet in the `ID` of that item, I want to have *e.g. "martin93"*.

The `ID` is usefull to append it to my **URL**, from which I want to **fetch some data**. But I want the user to choice a *"normal" name*, instead of weird (for example FaceBook) url name.

**IMPORTANT:** The facebook example is just given for explanation purposes, I am trying to achieve something else, but very similar (with ID I want to fetch the real URL's name, that is not nice to read, if I'd put it directly into Spinner).

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually you have 2 arrays. One with the display String, one with the thing you want to use. When you select an item based on the String, you receive the selected index, which you use to access the other array

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Typically you would have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="planets_array_values" translatable="false">
        <item>merc</item>
        <item>ven</item>
        <item>eart</item>
        <item>mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then populate the spinner with `planets_array`, and

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    String value = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array_values)[pos];
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am searching for! Thanks! :)

Comment: My concern about this solution is: what if the options are sorted alphabetically when presented to the user? In your example, "Earth" would be the third item in the English list, but if the list is for example in Spanish, it would be "Tierra" and it would be the last item (forth position) in the list.

Comment: Then have `planets_array_values` "translated" in all languages so that it stays consistent with the `planets_array` array

Comment: Saved my Time, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If it is not needed to translate IDs you could map the translatable array entries to IDs in code. Advantage of that would be that you can avoid accidential order mismatches between IDs and values. For that use string resources for every array entry:

```
<string-array name="my_array" translatable="false">
    <item>@string/text_1</item>
    <item>@string/test_2</item>
    ...
</string-array>

<string name="text_1">My first entry</string>
<string name="text_2">My second entry</string>
...
```

In code retrieve the string resources and put them as key + ID into a hash map:

```
val myArrayIdMap: HashMap<String, String> = java.util.HashMap()
myArrayIdMap[getString(R.string.text_1)] = "id-1"
myArrayIdMap[getString(R.string.text_2)] = "id-2"
...
```

To get the ID of a specific string use the map, for example if the string array is used in a spinner, the select listener could retrieve the ID:

```
...
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    val selectedEntry: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
    val id: String = myArrayIdMap.get(selectedEntry)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't give ID to individual array items.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) you may see syntax. 
 To be short this is example from mentioned docs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And this is how you get access to strings:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

**Updated**
To achieve your goal you may store separated name and some additional info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="names">
        <item>Martin:martin93</item>
        <item>Maria:mary1985</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then just use `String.split()` method to get two (or more) parts.
**Note** that it may be necessary to choose more complicated separator than ':'.
And to use it directly in the Spinner you should implement your own adapter.

Comment: This I ofcourse know, but I am trying to find an alternative. There always exists. Hoped that there is a way to do it directly.
I'm thinking of instead creating `string-array`, I make only `strings`, and then add them to `array`, so that I can use it with `Spinner`. What do you think? Becase then in `<string name="">` I can define the "ugly URL".

Comment: Added couple of words about adapter

Comment: I ge t the idea about the String.split(), curious if it will work! :)

Comment: split() works fine:) But answer by @njzk2 is more concise so it's better in your exact case. (I use separated string when I may have variable number of string parts).

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that any strings can be translated and/or reused, and spinner items can be sorted any way. IDs can also be translatable, if needed.

In strings.xml:

```xml
    <string name="id_one" translatable="false">1</string>
    <string name="id_two" translatable="false">2</string>
    <string name="id_three" translatable="false">3</string>

    <string name="name_one">name one</string>
    <string name="name_two">name two</string>
    <string name="name_three">name three</string>

    <string-array name="items">
        <item>@string/name_one</item>
        <item>@string/id_one</item>

        <item>@string/name_two</item>
        <item>@string/id_two</item>

        <item>@string/name_three</item>
        <item>@string/id_three</item>
    </string-array>
```

Data transfer object:

```java
public class SpinnerItem {
    //it seems better to have some kind of validation,
    //just in case name and id were mixed up in strings.xml
    public final String name;
    public final Integer id;

    public SpinnerItem(
            String name,
            Integer id
    ) {

        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```java
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> {

    public SpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<SpinnerItem> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        SpinnerItem spinnerItem = getItem(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;

        if (textView == null) {
            textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
        }

        textView.setText(spinnerItem.name);

        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        SpinnerItem spinnerItem = getItem(position);

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;

        if (textView == null) {
            textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }

        textView.setText(spinnerItem.name);

        return textView;
    }
}
```

This is for fragment, but it can be used in activity:

```java
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        mySpinner = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<?> myAdapter =
                new SpinnerAdapter(
                        getContext(),
                        getSpinnerItemDTOs(R.array.items)
                );
        mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                useItemData();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            }

        });

        return fragmentView;
    }

    private void useItemData() {
        SpinnerItem myDto = (SpinnerItem) mySpinner.getSelectedItem();
        //Do anything
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<SpinnerItem> getSpinnerItemDTOs(@ArrayRes int id) {
        String[] strings = getResources().getStringArray(id);
        ArrayList<SpinnerItem> spinnerItems = new ArrayList<>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < strings.length) {
            spinnerItems.add(new SpinnerItem(
                    strings[i++],
                    Integer.parseInt(strings[i++])
            ));
        }

        return spinnerItems;
    }
```