# Performing a conditional statement against a translatable string

Tags: java, android

I’ve got a spinner in my app which displays several distance units, which are pulled from `strings.xml` (which looks like so):

```
<string-array name="distance_units_array">
        <item>miles</item>
        <item>kilometers</item>
        <item>meters</item>
        <item>yards</item>
    </string-array>
```

If I need to perform some calculations on the distance the user has entered, but the calculation performed will vary depending on the distance unit. I can do this using the following, but it’s a horrible hack solution that becomes very painful with lots of languages.

```
if (distanceUnit = “kilometres” || distanceUnit = “kilómetros” || etc){
    //Do stuff
}
if (distanceUnit = “miles” || distanceUnit = “millas” || etc){
    //Do other stuff
}
```

Any suggestions on a better implementation? I feel like each `distanceUnit` needs an ID so I can compare against that rather than the translation of it, but I’m not sure how to do that when the strings are stored in `strings.xml`.

Comment: One more option, but a bit outdated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236319/3999808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start comparing with their IDs not with their content.

```
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           switch(position) {
               case 0 : //calculate miles
               case 1 : //calculate kilometres
               .....
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Ahhh man, I feel like such an idiot. I thought that the spinner list re-orders to bring the selected item to the top, so I couldn't use the list position. Thank you!

Comment: It's better to use a `switch`.