# Get item value of the spinner instead of spinner string value

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

In my application, I need to get the value of my spinner.
For example, I have a spinner "city" which is populated with string-array (strings.xml)
The user selects a value in the spinner, for example "Façade du poste extérieur" and I have to retrieve the value of the spinner in the form of an id linked to the value of "Façade du poste extérieur".

```
<!-- Mulitchoix emplacement antenne --> <string-array name="emplacement_antenne">
    <item value="521">Façade du poste extérieur</item>
    <item value="522">Pignon extérieur poste</item>
    <item value="523">Mur intérieur</item>
    <item value="524">Intérieur sur appareil</item> </string-array>
```

How to retrieve the id when the user selects "Façade du poste extérieur" for example?
For the moment I use this command line :

```
formulaireTypeAtn = spinner_type_antenne.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
```

How to get the item value instead of "getSelectedItem().toString()" ???

EDIT :

```
Spinner spinner_type_antenne;
spinner_type_antenne = findViewById(R.id.spinner_type_antenne);

        btnValider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
formulaireTypeAtn = spinner_type_antenne.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
  }
}
```

Comment: This can not be done in this way there is no value attribute in strings.xml file

Comment: What do you think if I put the ID inside the item and trim the value to get only the ID ?

Comment: Depends on the adapter, you can also put the value in the separate array and get the index of selected item and get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I foud the solution by myself :)

```
String formulaireTypeAtn, FormulaireTypeAtnFin;

formulaireTypeAtn = String.valueOf(spinner_type_antenne.getSelectedItemId());

            if (formulaireTypeAtn.equals("0")){
                FormulaireTypeAtnFin = "518";
            }
            if (formulaireTypeAtn.equals("1")){
                FormulaireTypeAtnFin = "519";
            }
            if (formulaireTypeAtn.equals("2")){
                FormulaireTypeAtnFin = "520";
            }
```

So, when the user click on the spinner and make a choice, it select one of the items in the spinner and I get the ID of the choice (0, 1, 2, 3, etc)
I created a condition which allows to define a value to a variable according to the ID selected in the spinner. So, I return the desired value.

Comment: Your solution is fine but take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236319/6076979

Answer (score 0):

get the position of selected item :

```
formulaireTypeAtn = spinner_type_antenne.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Comment: I need to get an ID that i've define by myself.
For example :
521 = Façade du poste extérieur
522=Pignon extérieur poste
523=Mur intérieur
524=Intérieur sur appareil

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following inside `setOnItemSelectedListener` function

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);//add values to the list
int SelectedIndex = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
int value = list.get(SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below code it is working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  if (array[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Selected spinner value")) {
  String value = array_value[i];
  }
}
```