# How can I discriminate the selected item of a Spinner by its text when using multilanguage items in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner, multilingual, selecteditem, items

I am trying to discriminate the selected item of a Spinner by its (multilanguage) text.

Here is my default strings.xml content:

```
<string-array name="spinner_items">
    <item>length</item>
    <item>weight</item>
    <item>temperature</item>
</string-array>
```

And this is another strings.xml (Italian language) content:

```
<string-array name="spinner_items">
    <item>lunghezza</item>
    <item>peso</item>
    <item>temperatura</item>
</string-array>
```

I set up my Spinner items in this way:

```
val items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.spinner_items)
spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items)
```

And then I add the item selected listener:

```
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        when(spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) {
            "length" -> actionLength()
            "lunghezza" -> actionLength()
            "weight" -> actionWeight()
            "peso" -> actionWeight()
            "temperature" -> actionTemperature()
            "temperatura" -> actionTemperature()
        }
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
}
```

Everything works fine but the problem is that everytime I add a new language locale, I have to remember to add the specific string translation inside the when block.
Is there a more "dynamic" way to do this?

Comment: Lyou cant look item by transletable values! Solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235970/can-i-give-an-id-to-an-item-in-string-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past and here is how I solved it.
Edit your strings.xml files by adding a string resource name for each items in your array, for example:

Default strings.xml

```
<string name="length">length</string>
<string name="weight">weight</string>
<string name="temperature">temperature</string>

<string-array name="spinner_items">
    <item>@string/length</item>
    <item>@string/weight</item>
    <item>@string/temperature</item>
</string-array>
```

Italian strings.xml

```
<string name="length">lunghezza</string>
<string name="weight">peso</string>
<string name="temperature">temperatura</string>

<string-array name="spinner_items">
    <item>@string/length</item>
    <item>@string/weight</item>
    <item>@string/temperature</item>
</string-array>
```

So in your code, you'll have:

```
when(spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) {
    getString(R.string.length) -> actionLength()
    getString(R.string.weight) -> actionWeight()
    getString(R.string.temperature) -> actionTemperature()
}
```

I hope I was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `position`:

```
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            when(position) {
              0 -> actionLength()
              1 -> actionWeight()
              2 -> actionTemperature()
            }
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
    }
```

In your array use:

```
<string-array name="spinner_items">
    <item>@string/length</item>
    <item>@string/weight</item>
    <item>@string/temperature</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: In this way, if for example I add a new language and I swap item positions in the string-array, I have to double check everything.
For example, if I add a new string-array with length, temperature and weight the two values are swapped and so the position method doesn't work correctly

Comment: @Turbo check the updated answer. Just define an unique array with string refs. In this way you can't swap items.

Comment: I like your answer but I think the other one is "better" because it is not related to the position, as I required the text in my question.
If for example one day I swap the items position in the string-array, I have to edit the code according to my edits.
If I check items using names instead of position, it is unique every time.
I hope you understand what I mean.